Circular imports/references between highly-dependent base-class and many sub-classes
Circular imports can drive you mad in Python. Here's one I'm too stupid to solve.
I have a base class with lots of functionality, that needs to emit itself, and also all kinds of its sub-classes:
# base.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from a import A
    from b import B

class BaseClass:
    def foo(self) -> A:
        pass
    def bar(self) -> B:
        pass
    def baz(self) -> BaseClass:
        pass

And there are the several sub-classes, which in comparison are relative lightweight and there are many more of them:
# a.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from base import BaseClass
    from b import B

class A(BaseClass):
    def foo(self) -> B:
        pass
    def bar(self) -> BaseClass:
        pass

and another one:
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from base import BaseClass
    from a import A

class B(BaseClass):
    def foo(self) -> A:
        pass
    def bar(self) -> BaseClass:
        pass

However I try to run this, it will fail due to circular imports.
from a import A
from b import B

my_a:A = A()
my_b:B = my_a.foo()

How can I solve this puzzle? The problem is that all classes need to deal with the base class and 0...N subclasses. Type hints/annotations are a must, as the code is part of an open-source library.
As of today, I have all the code in just one file, but that's a mess with 2500 lines of code.

How can a Superclass depend on subclass and the subclass depend on superclass, simultaneously?

That is exactly the question. Within 1 file no problem, distributed over multiple files (maybe) impossible. The use case is a fluent interface with 12 subclasses, e.g. root.s.t.u.v.w.x.y.z, without limitation of depth and order. What object needs to be returned depends on the full sequence of previous objects. I could theoretically push the entire code down to sub-classes, but then I would end up with +10k lines of code.

After various attempts I found the (likely) only possibile solution to the problem: you need to inline the imports in all classes as follows.
The base class needs to look like this:
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from a import A
    from b import B

class BaseClass:
    def foo(self) -> 'A':
        from a import A
        return A()
    def bar(self) -> 'B':
        from b import B
        return B()
    def baz(self) -> BaseClass:
        return self

In all derived classes need to look like this:
# a.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

from base import BaseClass

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from b import B

class A(BaseClass):
    def foo(self) -> 'B':
        from b import B
        pass
    def bar(self) -> BaseClass:
        return self

So the trick is to use if TYPCHECKING: to isolate all cross-references and declare all these references using a strings, e.g. 'B', and import the required class at the moment it is needed with an inline statement like from b import B. All other potential solutions, e.g. using factory class, didn't worked.
Type hints are also working flawlessly.
Happy coding...
